# does software go to sleep when their window is minimised in windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I wanted to know if a software goes to sleep after its window is minimized or not? is it windows OS property to set the minimized program to sleep? or does the app dev has to send the software to sleep if its window is minimized?
the problem is that i have developed a software to manage web links using sfml/tgui in c++, its taking more GPU power than i had expected it to, even when its minimized its taking up too much RAM, anyone please help, **what should i do to make it efficient?**

Comment: if this not uwp app - no. in case uwp - yes, go to *Frozen* state

Comment: No. Windows software doesn't "go to sleep" just because its window is minimised.   If you want it to reduce CPU or GPU usage, you need to write code that responds to (say) the event sent to your program as its window is minimised by reducing said usage (and presumably also respond to other events, so it resumes work in response to other actions, such as the window being opened or maximised).   If you don't write specific code for the purpose, you can't expect CPU or GPU usage to reduce while your program's window is minimised.

Comment: Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 1):

The windows model is that your UI thread is pretty much asleep all the time anyway. Windows wakes up that thread when it has a message for you. Now obviously a minimized window gets much less messages, but it could still get timer messages for instance.

Non-UI threads such as ordinary `std::thread`s are entirely different. They run all the time. As far as Windows knows, the user might be waiting for a result from them, so they're not put to sleep arbitrarily, but they might be put to sleep if there are too many threads for the available CPU cores.